# Macbook pro 2017 - Second monitor is not full screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina

I'm using the second monitor for my Macbook pro (not mirror, just as the secondary screen), but unfortunately, it's not filling the entire screen for some reason.

I've tried almost everything but it looks like a weird bug.

Is there any solution for this problem?

I'm attaching a photo of the monitor (the black area should be filled-the monitor is bezel-less designed).
I'm using Samsung's S24R350FHE monitor.

Thank you for the help
[image]

[image: macbookpro description]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We're missing something here.  The only "black area not filled" is the bezel.  Can you show both screens?  Also include your specific MacBook Pro model, the model of your monitor and how you have it set up in System Preferences → Displays.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the missing information. The monitor is bezel-less so there shouldn't be a black area. I've tried connecting different laptop (running Windows) and it was filling the entire screen.

Comment: Both screens as in the physical screens.